# How can I use executemany to insert into MySQL a list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm currently using MySQL and Python to scrape data from the web. Specifically, I am scraping table data and inserting it into my database. My current solution works, but I feel it is extremely inefficient and will most likely lock up my database if I don't rewrite the code. Here is what I currently use (partial code):

```
itemBank = []
for row in rows:
    itemBank.append((tempRow2,tempRow1,tempRow3,tempRow4)) #append data

#itemBank List of dictionaries representing data from each 
row of the table. i.e. 
('Item_Name':"Tomatoes",'Item_Price':"10",'Item_In_Stock':"10",'Item_Max':"30")

for item in itemBank:
    tempDict1 = item[0]
    tempDict2 = item[1]
    tempDict3 = item[2]
    tempDict4 = item[3]

    q = """ INSERT IGNORE INTO
         TABLE1   
        (
           Item_Name,
           Item_Price,
           Item_In_Stock,
           Item_Max,
           Observation_Date
         ) VALUES (
           "{0}",
           "{1}",
           "{2}",
           "{3}",
           "{4}"
           )
        """.format(tempDict1['Item_Name'],tempDict2['Item_Price'],tempDict3['Item_In_Stock'],
                   tempDict4['Item_Max'],getTimeExtra)

    try:
        x.execute(q)
        conn.commit()
    except:
        conn.rollback()
```

Executing each row of the table is cumbersome. I've tried using `executemany`, but I can't seem to figure out how to access the values of the dictionaries correctly. 
So, how can I use `executemany` here to insert into the database given the structure of my data?

Comment: The code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. What do you think it would do if there were quotes in the values? It needs to be pointed out.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
itemBank = [] 
for row in rows:
    itemBank.append((
        tempRow2['Item_Name'],
        tempRow1['Item_Price'],
        tempRow3['Item_In_Stock'],
        tempRow4['Item_Max'], 
        getTimeExtra
        )) #append data


q = """ insert ignore into TABLE1 (
        Item_Name, Item_Price, Item_In_Stock, Item_Max, Observation_Date ) 
        values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)           
    """

try:
    x.executemany(q, itemBank)
    conn.commit()
except:
    conn.rollback()
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: Does `executemany` sends the entire list in a go or run individual queries?

Comment: @Volatil3 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who needs to use "insert or update" instead of "insert ignore" below query can be used

```
q = """ INSERT INTO TABLE1 (Item_Name, Item_Price, Item_In_Stock, Item_Max, Observation_Date ) 
        values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Item_Name = VALUES(Item_Name), 
        Item_Price = VALUES(Item_Price), Item_In_Stock = VALUES(Item_In_Stock), Item_Max = VALUES(Item_Max), 
        Observation_Date = VALUES(Observation_Date)       
    """
```

If Item_Name is the primary key of the TABLE1, then remove it from update part as below, since in update, primary key need not be updated

```
q = """ INSERT INTO TABLE1 (Item_Name, Item_Price, Item_In_Stock, Item_Max, Observation_Date ) 
        values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Item_Price = VALUES(Item_Price), Item_In_Stock = VALUES(Item_In_Stock), Item_Max = VALUES(Item_Max), 
        Observation_Date = VALUES(Observation_Date)       
    """
```