# TypeError: not enough arguments for format string for mysqldb

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

I am trying to push a large csv of data into a `mysql` database and keep getting errors so I have simplified the insert to the following. I have seen a number of similar questions on here, but I haven't been able to get those to work for me. What am I missing? It should also note that it prints fine when I try that.

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
con = mdb.connect(host='', port=3306, user='', passwd='', db='')


cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO schema.table (Account_Number, Sales_Total) "
                       "VALUES(%s, %s)", ('Account 1', 2))
```

error:

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use executemany to instert into mysql a list of dictionaries in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244565/how-can-i-use-executemany-to-instert-into-mysql-a-list-of-dictionaries-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`executemany()` should be passed a sequence of tuples as the second argument (see [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html)). The following should work for you:

```
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO schema.table (Account_Number, Sales_Total) "
                   "VALUES(%s, %s)", [('Account 1', 2)])
```

Explanation for the strange error message: In your code you are passing a single tuple, which is also a sequence, so `executemany()` tries to format the query with just `'Account 1'`, and therefore complains that it doesn't have enough arguments.

Edit:

P.S. Strings are also sequences (of characters), but specifically string formatting treats them as a single value instead of as a sequence of characters. Otherwise, the original code would have created an error complaining about too many arguments instead of too few...