# Insert Data to SQL Server Table using pymssql

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, pymssql

I am trying to write the data frame into the SQL Server Table. My code:

```
conn = pymssql.connect(host="Dev02", database="DEVDb")
cur = conn.cursor()
query = "INSERT INTO dbo.SCORE_TABLE VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
cur.executemany(query, df_sql)
conn.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

The dimension of the `df_sql` is `(5860, 20)` i.e. the number of columns in the data frame is same as the number of columns in the SQL Server Table. Still I am getting following error:

> ValueError: more placeholders in sql than params available

**UPDATED BELOW**

As per one of the comments, I tried using `turbodbc` as below:

```
conn = turbodbc.connect(driver="{SQL Server}", server="Dev02", Database="DEVDb")
conn.use_async_io = True
cur = conn.cursor()
query = "INSERT INTO dbo.STG_CONTACTABILITY_SCORE VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
cur.executemany(query, df_sql.values)
cur.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

I am getting following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
>   ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I don't get it. What is wrong here. I see `df_sql.values` and I don't find anything wrong.

The first row of ndarray is as below:

```
[nan 'DUSTIN HOPKINS' 'SOUTHEAST MISSOURI STATE UNIVERSITY' 13.0
  '5736512217' None None 'Monday' '8:00AM' '9:00AM' 'Summer' None None None
  None '2017-12-22 10:39:30.626331' 'Completed' None '1-11KUFFZ'
  'Central Time Zone']
```

Comment: Perhaps this post will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/18245311/7948962

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you just need to specify each column name and don't forget the table must have the id field to charge the data frame index:

```
conn = pymssql.connect(host="Dev02", database="DEVDb")
cur = conn.cursor()
query = """INSERT INTO dbo.SCORE_TABLE(index, column1, column2, ..., column20)
            VALUES (?, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, 
            %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
cur.executemany(query, df_sql)
conn.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Ok I have been using pandas and I exported the last data frame to csv like:

```
df.to_csv('new_file_name.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
```

Then I just used `pyobdc` and `BULK INSERT` Transact-SQL like:

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(DRIVER='{SQL Server}', Server='server_name', Database='Database_name', trusted_connection='yes')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("""BULK INSERT table_name
               FROM 'C:\\Users\\folders path\\new_file_name.csv'
               WITH
               (
                   CODEPAGE = 'ACP',
                   FIRSTROW = 2,
                   FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
                   ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
               )""")
conn.commit()

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

It was a second to charge 15314 rows into SQL Server. I hope this gives you an idea.

Comment: Thank you @virtualdvid for your help and sorry for the late acknowledgment. This works.

Comment: @virtualvid: I am trying to use your BULK INSERT suggestion for one of my projects but I keep getting **Operating system could not locate the path" of new_file_name.csv. The file is in the path that I am specifying. Can you think of what could be the issue?

Comment: @KrishnangKDalal Can you show me the line that you are using?

Comment: I have posted on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48774516/bulk-insert-into-sql-server-table-using-pyodbc

Comment: How would this look if data had to go in schema 'myschema'  instead of into 'dbo'?
All my tables have a prefix 'ms_<tablename>'  but I would like them to be 'myschema.'ms_<tablename>'..   However, if I replace 'ms_' with 'myschema.ms_' all tables look like this: 'dbo.myschema.ms_<tablename>' ...

Answer (score 2):

Possibly `executemany` treats each row in the `ndarray` from your `df.values` call as **one** item since there are no comma separators between values. Hence, the placeholders outnumber actual binded values and you receive the mismatch error.

Consider converting array to a tuple of tuples (or lists of lists/tuple of lists/list of tuples) and then pass that object into `executemany`:

```
query = "INTO dbo.SCORE_TABLE VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"    
sql_data = tuple(map(tuple, df.values))

cur.executemany(query, sql_data)
cur.commit()
```

Comment: Nop, I tried converting an array to a tuple of tuples and list of lists but getting `turbodbc.exceptions.DatabaseError: Invalid number of parameters (expected 0, got 20)` error

Comment: This was for pymssql as placeholders are different. Try with `?` in turbodbc.

Comment: I think it is working but my IT team has added an identity column to which I am not able to insert any values by turning IDENTITY_INSERT OFF due to permission issues and I am not able to proceed without providing any values for that column. I will accept the answer once I have it sorted out from my end. Thank you

Comment: If identity field is same name as column in dataframe, drop that column in pandas and remove one placeholder then try again. Identity columns are autonumber fields that the database engine auto-inserts with new rows and not user.

Comment: Yes, I tried that and I am getting this error: `turbodbc.exceptions.DatabaseError: ODBC error
state: IM002
native error code: 0
message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified`. I definitely have the table in my database since I am able to insert data using `to_sql`

Comment: That looks like a connection error not query execution. Comment out everything and see if `connect()` line works.

Comment: You were right. It was a connection error and I fixed that but Iam still getting this error: `turbodbc.exceptions.DatabaseError: ODBC error
state: 42S02
native error code: 208
message: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'dbo.STG_CONTACTABILITY_SCORE'.`

Comment: Are you specifying a database in connection? If not default might not be your database. Try qualifying with dbname: `DEVDb.dbo.STG_CONTACTABILITY_SCORE`. Otherwise, I would re-try with pymssql. Until now, I never heard of turbodbc.

Comment: I got it working. Thanks a lot for all bearing with me. Your help was very helpful. Cheers and happy new year.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me-

```
insert_query = """INSERT INTO dbo.temptable(CHECK_TIME, DEVICE, METRIC, VALUE, TOWER, LOCATION, ANOMALY, ANOMALY_SCORE, ANOMALY_SEVERITY)
            VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
write_data = tuple(map(tuple, data_frame.values))
cursor.executemany(insert_query, write_data)
con.commit()
cursor.close()
con.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you want to use [DataFrame.to_sql()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) method:

```
df_sql.to_sql('dbo.SCORE_TABLE', conn, index=False, if_exists='append')
```

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that but I have read that pandas `to_sql` is slower than `pymssql` for a large amount of data. Do you think there is a major performance difference between two methods when dealing with a large amount of data? By large amount, I mean ~80k to 100k rows and 20 columns

Comment: @KrishnangKDalal, consider using [turbodbc](http://turbodbc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/advanced_usage.html#advanced-usage-numpy-parameters)

Comment: see the updated question. `turbodbc` is really a nice package but I am still getting an error.

Comment: @KrishnangKDalal ... did you actually try the `to_sql` method and test yourself, and even with an SQLAlchemy engine instead of a raw connection? What you hear may not always be true!

Comment: @Parfait: yes, I have tested `to_sql` and it takes little more than 7 mins to insert 26646 rows. I want to compare other methods but for that, I have to get other methods working.

Answer (score 0):

pymssql has a bulk_copy functionality now since v.2.2

The fastest way to insert data to a SQL Server table is often to use the bulk copy functions, for example:

```
conn = pymssql.connect(server, user, password, "tempdb")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE example (
        col1 INT NOT NULL,
        col2 INT NOT NULL
    )
""")
cursor.close()

conn.bulk_copy("example", [(1, 2)] * 1000000)
```

https://pymssql.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pymssql_examples.html#bulk-copy

It has some limitations, [see issues list](https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20bulk_copy):