# BULK INSERT into SQL Server table using pyodbc: cannot find file

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I know this kind of question has been asked before but still couldn't find the answer I'm looking for. I'm doing bulk insert of the csv file into the SQL Server table but I am getting error shown below:

**My Code:**

```
df_output.to_csv('new_file_name.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={SQL Server}; PORT=1433; SERVER=Dev02; DATABASE=db;UID='';PWD='';')
curr = conn.cursor()
print("Inserting!")
curr.execute("""BULK INSERT STG_CONTACTABILITY_SCORE
               FROM 'C:\\Users\\kdalal\\callerx_project\\caller_x\\new_file_name.csv'
               WITH
               (
                 CODEPAGE = 'ACP',
                 FIRSTROW = 2,
                 FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
                 ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
                 );""")
conn.commit()
```

The Error:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
>   Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot bulk load because the file
>   "C:\Users\kdalal\callerx_project\caller_x\new_file_name.csv"
>   could not be opened. Operating system error code 3(The system cannot
>   find the path specified.). (4861) (SQLExecDirectW)')

'new_file_name.csv' is in the specified path. I tried changing the path to just 'new_file_name.csv' since it is in the folder from where I am running the script still it throws a

> file does not exists

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong here. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Is the code file .py in the same path?
 `C:\\Users\\kdalal\\callerx_project\\caller_x\\`

Comment: yes, It is in the same path

Comment: try `df_output.to_csv('C:\\Users\\kdalal\\callerx_project\\caller_x\\new_file_name.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: Is the SQL Server instance on a different machine from the one that is running your Python code?

Comment: @virtualdvid: I'll get back to you on that. Thank you.

Comment: @GordThompson: yes, I am trying to bulk insert csv file from my windows machine to SQL Server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The BULK INSERT statement is executed on the SQL Server machine, so the file path must be accessible from that machine. You are getting "The system cannot find the path specified" because the path

```
C:\\Users\\kdalal\\callerx_project\\caller_x\\new_file_name.csv
```

is a path on *your* machine, not the SQL Server machine.

Since you are dumping the contents of a dataframe to the CSV file you could simply use `df.to_sql` to push the contents directly to the SQL Server without an intermediate CSV file. To improve performance you can tell SQLAlchemy to use pyodbc's `fast_executemany` option as described in the related question

[Speeding up pandas.DataFrame.to_sql with fast_executemany of pyODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48006551/2144390])

Comment: Got it. I tried this and it worked. The performance was decent. Thank you.