# insert Python list of lists into PSQL database

Tags: python, psql

I have a Python list of lists and I would like to insert it into a PSQL database.

```
lsls = [[int1, int2, int3],[int4, int5, int6]]
```

I've tried the following command of the psycopg2 module, but it's not working:

```
cur.executemany("""INSERT INTO example(col1, col2) VALUES (%s, %s)""", lsls)
```

Integers in the first list should be added to col1 and integers in the second list to col2.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to transpose your list of lists. Try `list_by_rows = zip(*lsls)`, then give that as the argument to `executemany()`.

See here for an example that shows how executemany() works:

[How can I use executemany to insert into MySQL a list of dictionaries in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244565/how-can-i-use-executemany-to-insert-into-mysql-a-list-of-dictionaries-in-python)

Comment: Great, it works, thank you! However, I don't really understand why you need to transpose the list...