# how to insert an array into database in python?

Tags: mysql, sql, python-3.x

I have a database called my_python and I have a table called my_transport. There are 3 columns in the table: id, transport, and fee. for the first columns "id", I make it auto increment so that I don't have to insert any value into it. My question is how to insert the value of  my_trans and my_fee into the database table?

```
    import mysql.connector

    my_trans=['car','train','ship','train']  
    my_fee=[200,300,150,200]

    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                 database='my-python',
                                 user='root',
                                 password='')
        sql_insert_query = """INSERT INTO my_transport
                               (`transport`, `fee`) VALUES (my_trans, my_fee)"""
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        result = cursor.execute(sql_insert_query)
        connection.commit()
        print ("Record inserted successfully into table")  except mysql.connector.Error as error :
        connection.rollback() #rollback if any exception occured
        print("Failed inserting record into table {}".format(error))  finally:
         #closing database connection.
        if(connection.is_connected()):
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
            print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

I have try below code but it said:

```
"Failed inserting record into table 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'my_trans' in 'field list'"
```

Comment: Can you also include the error you are getting, for completeness? Or in case you are not getting an error, the expected output.

Comment: i got this message: "Failed inserting record into table 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'my_trans' in 'field list'

Comment: Do you want to insert the values comma seperated?

Comment: i want them inserted into different rows

Comment: @EdBangga i have try your suggestion and it result in this message:
Failed inserting record into table 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '[my_transport]
                               (transport, fee) VALUES ([my_trans' at line 1

Comment: @Saepul Anwar, I updated the query in answer section

Answer (score 1):

use .executemany to insert array of records as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244565/how-can-i-use-executemany-to-insert-into-mysql-a-list-of-dictionaries-in-python)

```
my_trans = []
my_trans.append('car', 200)
my_trans.append('train', 300)
my_trans.append('ship', 150)
my_trans.append('train', 200)

sql_insert_query = 'INSERT INTO my_transport
                               (transport, fee) VALUES (%s, %s)'
cursor = connection.cursor()
result = cursor.executemany(sql_insert_query, my_trans)
```

Comment: I got this message afterusing executemany: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
        "File "/home/acer/PycharmProjects/bs1/try.py", line 14, in <module>
        result = cursor.executemany(sql_insert_query, my_trans, my_fee)
     TypeError: executemany() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given".

Then i try to separate my_trans and my_fee but i got this message:

Failed inserting record into table Failed rewriting statement for multi-row INSERT. Check SQL syntax.

Comment: how about this?

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but the python code in this answer doesn't seem to be valid syntax...

Comment: `append()` is a function, you don't assign to it.