# executemany() not inserting all records to database

Tags: python, mysql, executemany

I'm trying to use execute many to insert four (4) records at a time to a MySQL Database table, using MySQL Connector driver.

The problem is executemany() is consistently "skipping" the first 3 records without throwing an error and I can't understand what's wrong.

I'm trying to insert the values in a list:

```
my_records = [(334, 20533, 387.5, 'Label1'), (335, 20534, 387.5, 'Label2'), (336, 108659, 387.5, 'Label3'), (337, 108660, 387.5, 'Label4')]
```

And then here's my code:

```
   try:
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=os.getenv('DBM_HOST', 'x.x.x.x'),
            user=os.getenv('DBM_USER', 'username'),
            passwd=os.getenv('DBM_PASSWORD', 'password'),
            database=os.getenv('DBM_NAME', 'my_database')
        )

        mycursor = mydb.cursor()

        sql = """
            INSERT INTO my_table (
                batch_id, user_id, assessment, label
            ) VALUES (
                %s, %s, %s, %s
            )
        """

        mycursor.executemany(sql, my_records)
        mydb.commit()
        mycursor.close()
        mydb.close()

        return True

    except Exception as exception:
        print(exception)
        return None
```

Does anyone know what's happening? Or why the first 3 records are not inserting?

Here's the table structure:

```
Field       Type                    Null    Key Default     Extra   
id          int(10) unsigned        NO      PRI             auto_increment
batch_id    int(10) unsigned        NO      MUL
user_id    int(10) unsigned        NO
assessment      decimal(10,2) unsigned  NO
label       varchar(250)            YES
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244565/how-can-i-use-executemany-to-insert-into-mysql-a-list-of-dictionaries-in-python

Comment: Can you show us the table definition?

Comment: hi @snakecharmerb, I updated my post and added the description of the table.

Comment: Can you add the output of `SHOW INDEXES FROM my_table;` (or even better, the original CREATE TABLE statement).