# How to pass form data into multiple sqlite3 rows

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I'm trying to pass form data in Flask into multiple rows of a sqlite database.

The form requires the user to enter multiple ingredients and ingredient amounts required, and I'm trying to pass these into individual rows, using the recipe name to group the rows together.

```
if request.method == "POST":

    rname = request.form.get('rname')
    customer_id = request.form.get('customer_id')
    ingredient_id = request.form.getlist('product_code')
    ingredient_amount = request.form.getlist('ingredient_amount')

    con = sqlite.connect('database.db')
    cur = con.cursor()
    sql = """INSERT INTO recipes (rname, customer_id, ingredient_id, ingredient_amount) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"""
    cur.executemany(sql, (rname, customer_id, ingredient_id, ingredient_amount,))
    cur.commit()
```

Error

> ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type

On the front-end, the data is being passed OK as I can see it within the network console.

Where is this code going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: do you have any sort of data validation? perhaps the data being passed through does not match the data types specified in the database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use executemany to insert into MySQL a list of dictionaries in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244565/how-can-i-use-executemany-to-insert-into-mysql-a-list-of-dictionaries-in-python).  It looks like you need to create a compound list with consistent number of values per row.  In other words, you need to duplicate the "single values" and interleave the lists so that they form one list per row.  Right now you are trying to submit some single values along with separate lists, but that won't work.  Also lookup web docs for `executemany`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass to `Cursor.executemany` a sequence of parameters (e.g a list of tuples, see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany)). Given error in your case means `rname` is not iterable (I am assuming it is a string).

You need to properly pack your data for `executemany` like so

```py
query_args = []

for ind, ingredient in enumerate(ingredient_id):
    data = (rname, customer_id, ingredient, ingredient_amount[ind])
    query_args.append(data)

cur.executemany(sql, query_args)
```