# Get XML element in list

Tags: python

I am getting all values by scanning the tags

```py
    list_values = []
    tags = ['Created', 'Comments', 'Name']
    for element in root.iter():
    if element.tag not in tags:
        continue
    print(element.text)
    list_values .append(element.text)

    print(list_values)
```

Getting all values in one array like ['12/2/2018','aa','John','13/2/2018','aa2','Tim','12/4/2018','aa','John','13/2/2018','gg','Kim']

Have to insert all these values in SQL. I want output like

1. ('12/2/2018','aa','John')
2. ('13/2/2018','aa2','Tim')
3. (12/4/2018','aa','John')

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the iter() as below:

```
data = ['12/2/2018','aa','John','13/2/2018','aa2','Tim','12/4/2018','aa','John','13/2/2018','gg','Kim']
it = iter(data)
print(list(zip(it,it,it)))
```

Output:

```
[('12/2/2018', 'aa', 'John'), ('13/2/2018', 'aa2', 'Tim'), ('12/4/2018', 'aa', 'John'), ('13/2/2018', 'gg', 'Kim')]
```

Comment: Cool solution! ;)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
data = ['12/2/2018','aa','John','13/2/2018','aa2','Tim','12/4/2018','aa','John','13/2/2018','gg','Kim']
[data[i:i + 3] for i in range(0,len(data),3)]
```

Output:

```
[['12/2/2018', 'aa', 'John'],
 ['13/2/2018', 'aa2', 'Tim'],
 ['12/4/2018', 'aa', 'John'],
 ['13/2/2018', 'gg', 'Kim']]
```

To convert to list of tuple use this:

```
data = ['12/2/2018','aa','John','13/2/2018','aa2','Tim','12/4/2018','aa','John','13/2/2018','gg','Kim']
[tuple(data[i:i + 3]) for i in range(0,len(data),3)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please let me know how can I insert this into the SQL database. How can I read this one by one or in one go I can Insert. Thanks again.

Comment: Depends on what database you are using, there should be some libraries that help you insert many at once

Comment: I am using SQL DB and import pyodbc. following this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244565/how-can-i-use-executemany-to-insert-into-mysql-a-list-of-dictionaries-in-python . not able to figure out how can i read the above-genertaed array.

Comment: try the tuple way in my edited answer and see if that works