# get_exchange_info() from Binance API

Tags: python, mysql, binance-api-client, python-binance

I am new to Python (I mean really new > 7 weeks in on my free time) , bear with me...

I am trying to get exchange info from Binance for a project.

I am using the python-binance package.I get the exchange info with:

```
   exch_info = client.get_exchange_info()
```

The result is a very complicated mix from which I want to extract 'baseAsset' and 'quoteAsset' and put it in a table I already have based on my field 'Ticker' ('symbol' in the response).

see https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/binance.html#binance.client.Client.get_exchange_info

I extract the list of dictionnaries I want by adding ['symbols']:

```
   exch_info = client.get_exchange_info()['symbols']
```

I have tried (don't judge me) but I am stuck. I want to end up with a MySQL query that currently looks like:

```
   exch_info = client.get_exchange_info()['symbols']
   mycursor.executemany(f"INSERT INTO `param_asset_binance` (Ticker,Coin1,Coin2) VALUES ( %(symbol)s, %(baseAsset)s, %(quoteAsset)s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Coin1 = VALUES(Coin1), Coin2 = VALUES(Coin2) ", exch_info)
    #mydb.commit()
```

My errors are:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mathi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\conversion.py", line 179, in to_mysql
    return getattr(self, "_{0}_to_mysql".format(type_name))(value)
AttributeError: 'MySQLConverter' object has no attribute '_list_to_mysql'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 395, in _process_params_dict
    conv = to_mysql(conv)
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\conversion.py", line 181, in to_mysql
    raise TypeError("Python '{0}' cannot be converted to a "
TypeError: Python 'list' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\xxxx\library_param.py", line 45, in <module>
    update_binance_exch_info()
  File "c:\Users\xxxx\library_param.py", line 42, in update_binance_exch_info
    mycursor.executemany(f"INSERT INTO `autobot_core`.`param_asset_binance` (Ticker,Coin1,Coin2) VALUES ( %(symbol)s, %(baseAsset)s, %(quoteAsset)s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Coin1 = VALUES(Coin1), Coin2 = VALUES(Coin2) ", exch_info)
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 652, in executemany
    stmt = self._batch_insert(operation, seq_params)
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 591, in _batch_insert
    tmp, self._process_params_dict(params))
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 403, in _process_params_dict
    raise errors.ProgrammingError(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing pyformat-parameters; Python 'list' cannot be converted to a MySQL type
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related to the `exch_info` parameter provided in the `execute_many`. As it is unable to convert the type list into MYSQL format.

```py
    params = [] 
    for row in exch_info:
        params.append({
            'symbol': row['symbol'], 
            'baseAsset': row['baseAsset'], 
            'quoteAsset': row['quoteAsset']
    })
```

```
mycursor.executemany(f"INSERT INTO `param_asset_binance` (Ticker,Coin1,Coin2) VALUES ( %(symbol)s, %(baseAsset)s, %(quoteAsset)s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Coin1 = VALUES(Coin1), Coin2 = VALUES(Coin2) ", params)
```

**Reference** :

[How can I use executemany to insert into MySQL a list of dictionaries in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244565/how-can-i-use-executemany-to-insert-into-mysql-a-list-of-dictionaries-in-python)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html